# PHP MVC Several Combobox from SQL

Tags: php, sql

Осваиваю MVC на PHP, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
На вьюхе у меня есть форма регистрации, в которой есть 2 разных комбобокса, значения должны забираться из БД, собственно в этом и вопрос, как реализовать второй комбобокс ?

> Controller_Register.php
>
> ```
> class Controller_Register extends Controller
> {
>
>   function __construct()
>   {
>       $this->model = new Model_Register();
>       $this->view = new View();
>   }
>
>   function action_index()
>   {
>       $data = $this->model->Register();
>       $this->view->generate('register_view.php', 'template_view.php', $data);
>   }
>
>   function action_add()
>   {
>       $datas = $this->model->add();
>       $this->view->generate('Register_added_view.php', 'template_view.php', $datas);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Model_Register.php
>
> ```
>     class Model_Register extends Model
> {
>     public $id = '';
>   public $name = '';
>   public $username = '';
>     public $password = '';
>     public $email = '';
>   public $class_id = '';
>   public $team = '';
>   public $contacts = '';
>   public $ispl = '';
>   public $ip = '';
>
>     public function __construct($id = null, $name = null,$username = null, $password = null, $email = null, $class_id = null, $team = null, $contacts = null, $ispl = null, $ip = null) 
>   {
>       $this->id = $id;
>     $this->name = $name;
>       $this->username  = $username;
>       $this->password = $password;
>     $this->email = $email;
>     $this->class_id = $class_id;
>     $this->team = $team;
>     $this->contacts = $contacts;
>     $this->ispl = $ispl;
>     $this->ip = $ip;
>     }
>
>   public function Register() 
>   {
>       $list = [];
>       $db = Db::getInstance();
>       $req = $db->query('SELECT * FROM teams order by name');
>
>       foreach($req->fetchAll() as $teams) 
>       {
>           $list[] = new Model_Register($teams['name']);
>       }
>
>       return $list;
>    }  
> }
> ```
>
> Register_view.php
>
> ```
> <select name="class_id" type="select" class="login" width=""><br>
>           <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
>           <?php 
>               foreach($data as $teams) 
>               { 
>                   echo '<option value='.$teams->id.'>'.$team->id.'</option>';
>                   } 
>           ?>
>       </select>
> ```

Первый комбобокс выводится, а вот второй как вывести - не пойму.
Подскажите пож-ста.

Comment: зачем вы привязываетесь к одной модели? Контроллер может обрабатывать разные модели данных, и возвращать данные для модели представления.

Comment: Так же как и первый? Получить из БД и передать во вьюху?

Comment: @u_mulder Контроллер дергает функцию Register, которая селектит список и возвращает массив, далее контроллер сохраняет массив и передает на вьюху. Вьюха циклом выдергивает все данные с запросом. Итого мы имеем только одну переменную $data, которая уже имеет значение первого комбобокса. А вот как второй массив передать - не ясно.

Comment: Узнать что вложенность массивов может быть неограниченна и передать в переменной `$data` два массива. Во вьюхе обращаться к массивам как `$data->list1`, `$data->list2` (или с помощью `[]`), уж не знаю как ваш секретный фреймворк это позволяет.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо, дошло :) в функции дергаю кверю, и в list добавляю 2 массива, а на вьюхе использую $data[0] \ $data[1].